# Double Superscript error with primes

Tags: errors, superscripts

Simple question,

Why does the following cause a double superscript error?

```
$$ H^{' '} $$
```

Removing the spaces `$$ H^{''} $$` produces the expected output.

Comment: The markup should be `H''`  `'` is a macro that turns into `^{\prime}` which is why you get a double superscript in the first case, the second is equivalent to `H^{{}^{\prime\prime}}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please read the following Q&A: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'` is made active in math mode both in plain TeX and LaTeX. It puts `\prime` at the superscript position: `^{\prime}`. However, consecutive `'` are quite common and would raise a double superscript error. Therefore the macro behind `'` checks the next token, whether it is again a `'`. If yes, the following `'` is added to the superscript. The number of consecutive `'` is not limited, but any other token as your space token stops it.

Since `'` is putting `\prime` at the superscript position already. Putting `'` into a superscript would move the `\prime` too high:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  H^{\prime\prime} = H'' \neq H^{''}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Example for plain TeX:

```
$$ H^{\prime\prime} = H'' \neq H^{''} $$
\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `'` acts as superscripted prime, i.e. you can write, e.g.,  `$f'$` instead of `$f^\prime$`.